# Reusing Json object to populate select options

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object generated for a datatables element. I want to reuse this code as input to a select option dropdown.

The object returns lots of data, but I only need the name and ID from it. 
Here's the object:

```
    {"data":[
{"DT_RowId":"row_2","suppliers":
    {"SupplierAcc":"BNP002","SupplierName":"BNP Paribas Leasing SolutionsLtd","SupplierAddr1":"Northern Cross","SupplierAddr2":"Basing View","SupplierAddr3":null,"SupplierAddr4":null,"SupplierCity":"Basingstoke","SupplierCounty":null,"SupplierPCode":null,"SupplierCountry":null}
},
    {"DT_RowId":"row_3","suppliers":{"SupplierAcc":"3663","SupplierName":"BFS Group Ltd T\/ 3663","SupplierAddr1":"Blackmoss Lane","SupplierAddr2":"Scarisbrick","SupplierAddr3":null,"SupplierAddr4":null,"SupplierCity":"Ormskirk","SupplierCounty":"Lancashire","SupplierPCode":"L40 9RW","SupplierCountry":"UK"}
}}],"options":[]}
```

I need the SupplerName and DT_Row_ID to populate a select option list

The code that generates the object is used for other things, and I wondered if there was a way to make use of it rather than recoding.

Regards
Pete

Comment: Simply loop over the object.data with $.each or native JavaScript (for prop in...) - http://jsfiddle.net/2v9rcqth/

Comment: There are a few ways to do this...what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the JSON to a variable (e.g.: `myData`), after which you can easily navigate through the object and pull out the values you need.

For example, the array containing the two objects with DT_RowID values 'row_2' and 'row_3' is accessible using `myData.data`.  Each element is accessed like a regular JavaScript array, e.g. `myData.data[0]`, `myData.data[1]`, etc.

Accessing the properties of each object is very straightforward. For example, accessing the `SupplierName` for the first (and only) supplier under `row_2` would look like this:

```
myData.data[1].suppliers.SupplierName;
```

In the example below, I have extracted the values you are looking for and appended them to a String containing the HTML required to populate the select with its options. I have assigned DT_RowId as the value and SupplierName as the displayed text.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/hzgbgqnu/

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var myData = {
    "data": [{
        "DT_RowId": "row_2",
            "suppliers": {
                "SupplierAcc": "BNP002",
                "SupplierName": "BNP Paribas Leasing SolutionsLtd",
                "SupplierAddr1": "Northern Cross",
                "SupplierAddr2": "Basing View",
                "SupplierAddr3": null,
                "SupplierAddr4": null,
                "SupplierCity": "Basingstoke",
                "SupplierCounty": null,
                "SupplierPCode": null,
                "SupplierCountry": null
        }
    }, {
        "DT_RowId": "row_3",
            "suppliers": {
                "SupplierAcc": "3663",
                "SupplierName": "BFS Group Ltd T\/ 3663",
                "SupplierAddr1": "Blackmoss Lane",
                "SupplierAddr2": "Scarisbrick",
                "SupplierAddr3": null,
                "SupplierAddr4": null,
                "SupplierCity": "Ormskirk",
                "SupplierCounty": "Lancashire",
                "SupplierPCode": "L40 9RW",
                "SupplierCountry": "UK"
        }
    }],
        "options": []
};

// Iterate through the JSON object and build the options for our select
var options = '';
for (i = 0; i < myData.data.length; i++) {
    // Access Supplier Name using:  myData.data[i].suppliers.SupplierName
    // Access DT_RowID using:  myData.data[i].DT_RowId
    options += '<option value=' + myData.data[i].DT_RowId + '>' + myData.data[i].suppliers.SupplierName + '</option>';
}

$(function () {
    // Populate the select options
    $('#mySelect').html(options);
    // Demonstrate that the value has been properly set
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        alert('Selected value: ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

PS:  The JSON in your post has an extra `}` near the end.  The last line: `}}],"options":[]}` should be: `}],"options":[]}`. If you have no use for `options`, you can cut it out by changing the last line to `}]};`.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation and example. I really lean from this level of help